# How to fetch selecteditems properties from listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have created an listview where the items are sorted under different categories. And I am trying to get the selectedItem of the listview to get into a property in my Viewmodel, I have followed the regular approach simply setting a binding to the SelectedItem property.

However, since I am now actually only setting the datacontext to my observable collection, and not touching the ItemsSource property (Or am I?), I believe Im missing some fancy xaml code to make the binding for SelectedItem work. Hopefully someone encountered similar issue.
xaml code, and the 2 properties declared in the viewmodel is dispalyed below.

```wpf
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="TileChangeType"                               
                  Source="{Binding TileChangeList.TileChangeListEntries}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Type" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ListView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="gridTiles" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="False"
                      DataContext="{StaticResource TileChangeType}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTileChange}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding IsAsync=True}">


            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <TextBlock Background="Aqua" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="X" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding X}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Y" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Y}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Z" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Z}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}" Width="40"/>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

            </ListView>
```

The model "SelectedTileChange" is declared as following:

```
    public TileChange SelectedTileChange
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    //Class contains an Observable Collection of the TileChange class (same class as SelectedItem is binding to)
    //E.g. ObservableCollection<TileChange> tileChangeListEntries;
    public TileChangeList TileChangeList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the datacontext of the usercontrol is set to the viewmodel that contains the `SelectedTileChange` property, you can bind to the `SelectedItem` property like this:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedTileChange, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

This will find the usercontrol, and bind to the `SelectedTileChange` property on its datacontext.

But normally you would just bind the `ListView` directly to the `CollectionViewSource` instead of setting its datacontext. That way you don't need to create this kind of `RelativeSource` binding:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TileChangeType}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTileChange}" />
```

Comment: Excellent answer! You just solved 2 issues in one! I have never managed to bind something using relative source, except for elements, since I have not used the prefix DataContext. ... , (had to set the whole elements datacontext instead). And now this works! 
Btw mind giving an example of "binding the listview directly to the collectionviewsource"?

Comment: @ETG87 Good to hear it worked. I've added some code to demonstrate how to bind directly to the collectionviewsource.